# SonarQube violation: Unused private method on inner class private constructor

Tags: java, sonarqube, inner-classes

I've used following code in my project. When I evaluated it using sonar it shows  `Unused private method` violation for the private constructor defined in `ObjectTypes` inner class. If I removed `ObjectTypes` constructor it shows `Hide Utility Class Constructor` violation. Please help me to find the best possible way to overcome this issue.

```
public final class Constants
{
  private Constants()
  {
  }

  public static final String KEY_SEPARATOR = " ~ ";      
  public static final String COMMON_SEPARATOR = " : ";

  public final class ObjectTypes
  {
    private ObjectTypes()
    {
    }
    public static final String ACTION_CODES = "Action Codes";
    public static final String ALL_ACTION_CODES = "All Action Codes";
    //more lines
  }
}
```

Comment: I can overcome this problem by changing private constructors into protected constructors in Inner classes. However, I don't think it is a good idea to use a protected constructor in a final class.

Answer (score 0):

This is the problem:

```
 private Constants()
  {
  }
```

And this:

```
private ObjectTypes()
    {
    }
```

You do not have to declare **EMPTY** constructors.

Comment: But, if I removed empty constructors, I can get different sonar violation saying `Hide Utility Class Constructor` for the corresponding classes

Comment: Check this out : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14398747/hide-utility-class-constructor-utility-classes-should-not-have-a-public-or-def

Comment: All problems comes for the inner class. Is there any way to overcome `Hide Utility Class Constructor` violation for the inner class without using a private constructor?

Comment: I have run out of ideas.

Comment: If you get `Hide Utility Class Constructor` for `ObjectTypes` it means that you have only `static` fields in `ObjectTypes`, what's the point of having such class?

Comment: @Massimo-SonarSourceTeam We use Constants class to store string literals and we used inner classes to cluster the constants class because it has huge set of literals.